# In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

When trying to run my code, for example

```
for ii= 1:10
   output(ii)=rand(3);
end
```

I get the error

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same
```

or

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
```

What does this error mean? What is the approach to get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error comes because you are trying to fill a variable chunk with more (or less) values than its size. In other words, you have a statement `A(:)=B` on where `size(A(:))` is different to `size(B)`.

In the example in the question, `rand(3)` returns a `3x3` matrix, however, `output(ii)` is just a single value (even if `output` may be bigger, `output(ii)` is just a single value of `output`), thus the value returned by `rand(3)` does not fit inside `output`.

In order to solve this problem, you need to change the the size of the `output` variable, so you have space to fit all the result.

There are 2 ways of doing this. One of them is by creating a **Matrix** that fits the return, e.g. `output=zeros(3,3,10)`.

Then we can change the code to

```
for ii= 1:10
   output(:,:,ii)=rand(3);
end
```

Alternatively, you can fill the `output` as a **cell array**. This is particularly useful when the return of the function changes sizes each time, e.g. `rand(ii);`

In that case, the following would work

```
for ii= 1:10
   output{ii}=rand(ii);
end
```

---

It is probable that unlike in the example in the question, in the real case you do not know the size of what the output returns, thus you do not know which of the two options to use to fix your code.

On possible way of learning that, is activating debugging help when the code errors, by typing `dbstop if error` in your command line. This will trigger a debugging stop when MATLAB throws an error, and you can type `size(rand(ii))` and `size(output(ii))` to see the sizes of both.

Often, reading the documentation of the function being used also helps, to see if different sizes are possible.

That said, the second option, cell arrays, will always ensure everything will fit. However matrices are generally a faster and easier to use in MATLAB, thus you should aim for the matrix based solution if you can.

Comment: This is meant to be a easy explanation of this common problem, feel free to edit/add information, I can convert it a community wiki

Comment: Please leave as it is.  This is a canonical duplicate that we need to link to in the future.