# Matlab - Mismatch number of elements of 2 matrix in using "for loop"

Tags: matlab, for-loop

This error is shown and I don't know how to solve this problem. I don't understand this error and it seems my problem is in the for loop. Can anyone help me

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be
>   the same. Error in...(line 13)

This is the code on line 13: `p(k)=exp(n/4)*phi;`

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
tmin=-10;
tmax=10;
t=tmin:0.01:tmax;
phi=zeros(size(t));
p=zeros(size(t)); 
k=0;
for n=-24:-1
k=k+1;
phi((-tmin+n/4)*100+1:(-tmin+(n+1)/4)*100+1)=1;
p(k)=exp(n/4)*phi;    
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563305/in-an-assignment-a-b-the-number-of-elements-in-a-and-b-must-be-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `phi` is `1x2001` double, and you are trying to assign it to a single value of `p`. One way to overcome this is to change the dimensions of `p` as follows

```
p=zeros(24, size(t,2));
```

in this case inside the for loop you can write

```
p(k,:)=exp(n/4)*phi;
```

So your `p(1,:)` for example will correspond to `n = -24`, etc.

Comment: @AliDibaj you are welcome. Consider accepting the answer if this solved your problem.